# 'android.support.test.espresso does not exist' when I want to use it to individual apk test

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

I need to do some auto testing jobs to an Android application without its source code. I found both robotium and espresso can do this job, I decided to use espresso because its Google support.

I would like to sign both the target apk and espresso test apk with the same signature, the target apk is the same as [this sample](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

[image]

When I start to coding the espresso test apk, I did the following jobs.

The build.gradle in Module:app:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tk.deedog.i01test"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```

The source code of my I01Test.java:

```
package tk.deedog.i01test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;

import static android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.onView;
import static android.support.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.click;
import static android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withText;


public class I01Test extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 {
    private static final String LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME = "tk.tubabe.instrustmen101.Instruments101";
    private static Class<?> launcherActivityClass;
    Activity i101Acitvity;

    static {
        try {
            launcherActivityClass = Class.forName(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public I01Test() {
        super(launcherActivityClass);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        i101Acitvity = getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
    }

    public void testButtonClick() {
        onView(withText("Send")).perform(click());
    }
}
```

When I tried to run this program, Android studio told me that `Error:(6, 44) error: package android.support.test.espresso does not exist`.

Comment: Everything you've posted looks OK. Is your I01Test.java under src/androidTest/ or src/main? It should be the former.

Comment: @Baqueta I just put the I01Test.java inside the src/androidTest/, and run the TestModule, but there's an error `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "tk.tubabe.instrustmen101.Instruments101" `. The testing apk and the target apk is two different apk with the same signature.

Comment: Should "tk.tubabe.instrustmen101.Instruments101" be "tk.tubabe.instrustmen**t**101.Instruments101"? You can just reference the class like normal, you don't need to use reflection to find it.

Comment: Trying to do exact the same thing without success yet, but I saw this ClassNotFoundException before. In my case, I assumed that applicationId "tk.deedog.i01test"  will be the package of my test apk, but gradle android plugin took it as the package of my app (target apk), and the package of test apk is "tk.deedog.i01test.test". And because "tk.deedog.i01test" actually contains test code, the launch activity isn't there.  I have a question about espresso test without source code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020893/gradle-android-instrumentation-test-without-app-source-code , no reply yet

Comment: Did you solve this issue?

Comment: I'm interested in this as well...

Comment: Can you actually show your project directory architecture ?

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and got it to work by checking my project structure. Are your tests under src/androidTest ? I had to refactor the name of my folder from test to androidTest

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue, one thing that was ruining my test build is the following line:

```
main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/AndroidTests', 'src/AndroidTest/java'] }
```

Remove test code from srcDirs:

```
sourceSets {
    ....
    main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Too late but may help someone.

My scenario was this -

I was running Android Studio 2.2(Stable). My androidTest folder was inside src/ . In the "Android" view, my java folder was showing normal java folder,test folder ,androidTest folder and a copy of the the androidTest folder under the name "java" (in green).
The culprit was

```
sourceSets {
....
main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java','src/androidTest'] }
...
}
```

Change this to the following -

```
sourceSets {
....
main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] }
...
}
```

My app level build.gradle looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "my.package.name"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0-debug"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false;
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:24.2.0'
androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
}
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
    // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test  runner
    // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support- annotations'
}


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd be better off not defining custom sourceSets. I just **comment**

`sourceSets`

from my build.gradle and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

On my app build.gradle this dependency was missing:
`androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't clearly understand what did you mean under

> ... Android application without its source code.

but why can't you call activity from the test class without reflection? Just how it was shown in *Espresso Start Guide*.

You have [activity](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/EspressoStartGuide) and appropriate [test](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testapp/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/testapp/SimpleActivity.java), take a look at the package, imported classes, extended class and constructor in those examples. I mean smth like this:

```
package com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.tests;

import static com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.Espresso.onData;
<...>

import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.testapp.R;
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.testapp.SimpleActivity;

import android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2;
import android.test.suitebuilder.annotation.LargeTest;

@LargeTest
public class BasicTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SimpleActivity> {

  public BasicTest() {
    super(SimpleActivity.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    getActivity();
  }

  <...>
```