# Espresso: error package does not exist

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-espresso

I'm trying add Espresso as a testing framework for my Android project and am getting the following runtime errors in running sample tests.

`error: package android.support.test.rule does not exist`

`error: package android.support.test.runner does not exist`

My folder structure is as follows:

`app/src/androidTest/java/com/[identifier]/support/[app_folders]`
`app/src/com/java/com/[identifier]/support/[app_folders]`

My `build.gradle` looks like the following minus redacted irrelevant statements.

```html
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral();
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
        gradleVersion = '2.13'
    }

    android {
        sourceSets {
            main {
                manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
                java.srcDirs = ['src']
                resources.srcDirs = ['src']
                aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
                renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
                res.srcDirs = ['res']
                assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
                jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
            exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        }

        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

        defaultConfig {
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
            applicationId privateHelpers.extractStringFromManifest("package")
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            versionCode Integer.parseInt("" + project.VERSION_CODE)
            versionName project.VERSION_NAME
        }

        lintOptions {
          abortOnError false;
        }

        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4096m"
            preDexLibraries = false
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
        debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
        releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:+"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+"
        compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
        compile "com.pushwoosh:pushwoosh:4.6.3"
        compile "io.branch.sdk.android:library:1+"
        compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
        compile 'io.intercom.android:intercom-sdk:3.0.20'
        compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
        compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.5'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.5.1'
        compile 'com.joshdholtz.sentry:sentry-android:1.6.0'
        compile 'com.instabug.library:instabug:4.0.7'
        compile 'com.workday:postman:1.3'
        compile ('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.0') {
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        compile 'com.workday:postman-processor:1.3'
        androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
        androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0-alpha1'
        androidTestCompile 'com.squareup:javawriter:2.5.1'
        androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test:rules:0.5') {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        }
        testCompile 'org.threeten:threetenbp:1.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                srcDir 'src'
            }
        }
    }

    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath 'net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.6' // Java annotation processing
            classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8' // Android annotation processing
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.6.1'
        apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.6.1'
        compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.3.0'
        apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.3.0'
        provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    }

    android {
        testBuildType "debug"

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['android.support.test.espresso does not exist' when I want to use it to individual apk test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956484/android-support-test-espresso-does-not-exist-when-i-want-to-use-it-to-individu)